# Inserting a node in an ordered linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a project and I need to insert a node in an ordered list. I tried this code but the program keeps on crashing.

The calling function is:

```
head = insertorder(node, head);
```

Here is the function definition code:

```
nodeptr_t insertorder(nodeptr_t nn, nodeptr_t head) {
    nodeptr_t w;

    w = head;
    if(head==NULL)
        return nn;

    while(w->next!=NULL && w->next->key < nn->key)
       w = w->next;

    w->next = nn;
    nn->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about the power of a debugger and [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, please don't typedef pointers.

Comment: @GillBates Excellent screen name :-)

Comment: please could you tell me more about debuggers cuz I am new to this field, and for the pointer it was one of the project specifications :/

Comment: if you need `nn->next = NULL;`, Also Need before `return nn;`

Comment: You have a logical problem of that you are not splicing in the new node.  Rather, you just add it and lop off everything which used to come after it.  But this should still not cause the program to crash, only for data to be lost.  As others have said, try using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
nodeptr_t insertorder(nodeptr_t nn, nodeptr_t head){
nodeptr_t w;

if(head==NULL || head->key >=nn->key)
{
    nn->next = head;
    head = nn; 
}
else
{
    w = head;
    while(w->next!=NULL && w->next->key < nn->key)
      { w = w->next;}
    nn->next = w->next;
    w->next = nn;
 }
 return head;
}
```

If possible, please copy the declaration of 'nodeptr_t' in your actual query.

Answer (score 2):

You are losing the tail after inserting a new node. You need to do the following:

```
...
while(w->next!=NULL && w->next->key < nn->key)
    w = w->next;
nn->next = w->next;
w->next = nn;
...
```

Comment: Also @Senouy should set the `head` pointer to the new node if `head` was originally `NULL`, not just returning `nn`

Comment: The problem is when I scanf numbers in order everything is good. but when I scanf them randomly the function insert only chooses those in order and insert them!!!